# Can I choose which HTML image to render using a Swift UITextView?

Tags: html, swift, uitextview

I'm using a UITextView to render HTML downloaded from a web API. My challenge is that in cases where multiple image files exist for different sized displays, images do not render.

Example: This image DOES render...

```
<figure data-align="right" data-img-src="https://uploads/original/image-02.jpg" data-ref-id="1300-627596" data-size="medium" data-ratio="1.2996254681648" data-width="267" data-embed-type="image" style="width: 267px">
    <a class="fluid-height" style="padding-bottom:130.0%" href="https://uploads/original/image-02.jpg" data-ref-id="1300-627596">
        <img alt="Praesent sed molestie lectus, sit amet dictum eros." src="https://uploads/original/image-02.jpg" srcset="https://uploads/original/image-02.jpg 267w" sizes="(max-width: 267px) 100vw, 267px" data-width="267"></a>
    <figcaption style=font-weight:500;font-size:13;color:666666>Pic 2 Caption</figcaption>
```

But this image does NOT render

```
<figure data-align="right" data-img-src="https://uploads/original/image-01.jpg" data-ref-id="1300-2086678" data-size="small" data-ratio="1.2257525083612" data-width="598" data-embed-type="image" style="width: 598px">
    <a class="fluid-height" style="padding-bottom:122.6%" href="https://uploads/original/image-01.jpg" data-ref-id="1300-2086678">
        <img alt="Praesent sed molestie lectus, sit amet dictum eros." src="https://uploads/scale_small/image-01.jpg" srcset="https://uploads/original/image-01.jpg 598w, https://uploads/scale_small/image-01.jpg.jpg 522w" sizes="(max-width: 522px) 100vw, 522px" data-width="522"></a>
    <figcaption style=font-weight:500;font-size:13;color:666666>Pic 1 Caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
```

I know it has something to do with the different image file names. Is there a way to select which file to use? Or, maybe add something to the header tag?

Header tag:

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title></head>
```

Thanks for the help

EDITED: This is how I'm loading the data into the UITextView

```
let inputString = "<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title></head><body><span style='font-family:-apple-system;font-size:17'>
  <h2 style=font-weight:800;color:0282F8>Sample Heading</h2>
  <p style=font-weight:300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
  <p style=font-weight:300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
  <h2 style=font-weight:800;color:0282F8>Sample Heading</h2>
  <p style=font-weight:300>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas congue posuere neque a pretium. Nullam viverra ex tortor, quis dictum urna pulvinar non. In tristique nisi libero, nec ornare orci consequat suscipit. Maecenas quis elit magna. Donec finibus semper nulla sit amet dignissim. Vestibulum consectetur ullamcorper justo. Ut tincidunt nisi ut porta ornare.</p>
</span></body>"

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<HTMLView>) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let data = Data(self.inputString.utf8)
            if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
                uiView.isEditable = false
                uiView.attributedText = attributedString
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: UITextView Sample]

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some context of *how* you're displaying this information in a `UITextView` (ie, add some code).

Comment: @jnpdx I updated the question to include a bit more context on how it's being displayed

Comment: I''m not sure if that's really an image name issue, and not a "HTML to NSAttributedString" Apple's parsing API doesn't parse every tag in HTML, only some. Use a `WKWebView` to handle really "every" HTML.